# VBA to Import Multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I know there were a lot of different topics to cover this question but nothing that worked for me... I have .xls Workbook with 3 Worksheets in it (Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3).

Each sheet would have 65536 rows in it (Sheet3 would have 25+ lines at the moment). I have found a code on the link below which supposed to do the job... But... it doesn't. It would only import 25k lines. Also, only Sheet1 would have headers, Sheet2 and Sheet3 on a Row1 would have data.

[Import Data from All Worksheets in a single EXCEL File into One Table via TransferSpreadsheet (VBA)](http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpAllWktsSepTbl)

The VBA I have only imports Excel files from the 1st tab. Is there a way to modify it so it would import all three Worksheets where only the first one has Headers?

```
    Private Sub cmdButton_Click()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

blnHasFieldNames = True
strPath = "C:\Folder\"
strTable = "dbo_tblTest"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")

If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
strPath = strPath & "\"
End If
If Dir(strPath & "*.*") = "" Then
MsgBox "The folder doesn't contain (visible) files"
Else

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Once purged LOOP file import
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames


     strFile = Dir()
Loop

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' LOOP TO MOVE FILES IN ARCHIVE FOLDER
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Dim fso As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    FromPath = "S:\Folder"  '~~> Change
    ToPath = "S:\Folder\Archive"    '~~> Change
    FileExt = "*"

    '~~> You can use *.* for all files or *.doc for word files

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    If fso.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If fso.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    fso.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

    Kill "S:\Folder\*"
    MsgBox "Files Successfully Imported"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried Excel's built-in [macro recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html)?  If you perform the import once manually Excel will record your actions as VBA.  You can then review, edit, tweak and rerun the code as required.

Comment: You have code linked. Please show an attempt based on it. The necessary modifications are minor.

Comment: @destination-data this is exactly what I have at the moment. VBA on excel that opens the file splits into 3 Workbooks from worksheets, then joins them and spits out one excel file with all records on one sheet... However, I'm trying to move away from Excel-based actions and use Access import... Unless you are suggesting to use Excel VBA to perform the same action in Access...

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. You have three questions here. 1) Why is the code not importing all records? 2) How can you turn headers on/off? 3) How can I import from multiple tabs? Strictly speaking, you should post three separate questions. Addressing all issues at once can get complicated. High level the answers are 1) Do you receive any error messages, and if so, what are they? 2) Read-up on *HasFieldNames* parameter of [TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method. 3) You need a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read over all of the sheets in the workbook, you need to add one more argument to the transfer spreadsheet command (the "Range" argument) and fully qualify it with the name of the worksheet:

```
'Put these with the rest of your variable declarations

 Dim objExcel As Object
 Dim wb As Object
 Dim ws As Object
 Dim strUsedRange As String

'Replace the current loop with the code starting from here

 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 Do While Len(strFile) > 0

     strPathFile = strPath & strFile
     Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile)

     For Each ws In wb.Worksheets()
         'Loop over all the sheets in the workbook

          strUsedRange = ws.UsedRange.Address(0,0)
          DoCmdTransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, ws.Name & "!" & strUsedRange
     Next ws

     wb.Close
     Set wb = Nothing

     strFile = Dir()

 Loop

 Set objExcel = Nothing
```

The advantage to this is that it will handle the worksheet names and the used ranges within the worksheets automatically using Excel's built-in Worksheets collection, which the loop simply iterates over.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is what you want.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean, blnEXCEL As Boolean, blnReadOnly As Boolean
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim objExcel As Object, objWorkbook As Object
Dim colWorksheets As Collection
Dim strPathFile As String, strTable As String
Dim strPassword As String

' Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      blnEXCEL = True
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0


' Replace C:\Filename.xls with the actual path and filename
strPathFile = "your_path_here\testit.xls"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"


blnReadOnly = True ' open EXCEL file in read-only mode

' Open the EXCEL file and read the worksheet names into a collection
Set colWorksheets = New Collection
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile, , blnReadOnly)
For lngCount = 1 To objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
      colWorksheets.Add objWorkbook.Worksheets(lngCount).Name

    ' Import the data from each worksheet into the table
    If lngCount = 1 Then
          DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
          strTable, strPathFile, False, colWorksheets(lngCount) & "$"
    Else
          DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
          strTable, strPathFile, False, colWorksheets(lngCount) & "$"
    End If

Next lngCount

' Close the EXCEL file without saving the file, and clean up the EXCEL objects
objWorkbook.Close False
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
If blnEXCEL = True Then objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

' Delete the collection
Set colWorksheets = Nothing

End Sub
```